# Flex AIR unzip

Tags: apache-flex, air, unzip

I am a newbie to Flex AIR. I am trying to create an application that will unzip the contents of a zip file & place them in a particular directory.

How can I achieve this? Is there any unzip library available for flex? Pls help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I achieve this?

Read the [ZIP specification](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). Implementing it is easy.

> Is there any unzip library available for flex?

Is Google down again? The first link takes me [here](http://ntt.cc/2008/01/19/actionscript-class-library-fzip.html).

Answer (score 2):

For AIR projects I used airxzip from coltware (google it). It has the capability to extract single file from archive, not loading it entire archive into memory.