# Unzip local file in adobe air

Tags: actionscript-3, air, zip, unzip

Does anyone know a good library to unzip local files in adobe AIR for with actionscript 3?

**I have:**

A local file named somefile.zip

**I need:**

To give some external library a path where I want to save the unzipped version of file.
It must be able to process the file and not load it all into the memory.

I found the FZip library - but it loads all archived data into the memory.
And also found the nochump library, but there is no such parameter to choose where I want to unzip the file.

Thanx for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665292/flex-air-unzip

Comment: there's a basic library here: https://code.google.com/p/aszip/

Answer (score 1):

Try FZip by Claus Wahlers from côdeazur brasil lab.

*"FZip is an Actionscript 3 class library to load, modify and create standard ZIP archives."*

http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/